# Performance of C++ Google dense_hash_set inserts

Tags: c++, hashmap

I have a C++ program that is inserting approx. 18 million numbers of type `uint64_t` into a google `dense_hash_set`.

The numbers are all the even numbers below 2^64 with the property

```
N >= radical(N)^4.
```

The inserts are an order of magnitude slower than, for example, inserting 18 million random numbers, or 18 million sequential numbers.

When performing the inserts, the code seems to spend most of its time executing the statement

```
if ( test_empty(bucknum) )
```

Is 18 million a sensible number of items to insert into a `dense_hash_set`?

Is there any way of speeding up the inserts?

Relevant lines are

```
uint64_t N;
google::dense_hash_set<uint64_t> evencandidates;
evencandidates.set_empty_key(-1);
.....
evencandidates.insert(N);
```

Comment: Maybe because you have to check if N>=radical(N)^4 ? You did not provide any code even. How are we supposed to answer?

Comment: The poor performance is not related to checking that N>=radical(N)^4 (I was previously using a std::unordered_set for the inserts which was also an order of magnitude faster).   

The full code is complicated, so I haven't included it in the post, have added the relevant lines.

Comment: @Armchair: Then make a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem. As a bonus, as you remove parts of the code that aren't needed to demonstrate the poor performance, you may discover that the problem is something else!

Answer (score 3):

Solved by replacing the default hash function with std::tr1::hash. The declaration of the dense hash set becoming:

```
google::dense_hash_set<uint64_t, std::tr1::hash<uint64_t> > evencandidates;
```

The criterion for choosing numbers to store,

```
N >= radical(N)^4 and N even
```

results in the numbers being stored have a lot of common factors, particluarly several powers of 2 for most numbers. Choosing a hash function that works well with this set of numbers solves the performance problem.